# kwarg "alines" validator returned False

Tags: python, mplfinance

The message is telling me something but I can't see it:

```
TypeError: kwarg "alines" validator returned False for value: "{'alines': [[(Timestamp('2020-09-08 00:00:00'), 40.0), (Timestamp('2021-03-19 00:00:00'), 35.82)], [(Timestamp('2020-09-08 00:00:00'), 35.82), (Timestamp('2021-03-19 00:00:00'), 35.82)], [(datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 17, 0, 0), '47.5'), (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 26, 0, 0), '47.5')], [(datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 25, 0, 0), '47'), (datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 19, 0, 0), '47')]], 'colors': ['b', 'g'], 'linestyle': '--'}"
    'Validator'   : lambda value: _alines_validator(value) },
```

It happens on this call:

```
mpf.plot(df_history, show_nontrading=True,
         alines=dict(alines=seq_of_points, colors=['b', 'g'], linestyle='--'),
         type='candle', style=s, savefig=bildpfad, 
         update_width_config=dict(candle_linewidth=0.4))
```

Comment: please provide more information.  I am certain that more information came along with the `TypeError` exception.  Please provide the entire exception trace.

Comment: You `alines` specification is failing here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/_arg_validators.py#L175-L181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have some strings in your `alines` specification where you should have floats.  This is what your `alines` specification looks like (pprint):

```py
{'alines': [[(Timestamp('2020-09-08 00:00:00'), 40.0),
             (Timestamp('2021-03-19 00:00:00'), 35.82)],
            [(Timestamp('2020-09-08 00:00:00'), 35.82),
             (Timestamp('2021-03-19 00:00:00'), 35.82)],
            [(datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 17, 0, 0), '47.5'),
             (datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 26, 0, 0), '47.5')],
            [(datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 25, 0, 0), '47'),
             (datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 19, 0, 0), '47')]],
 'colors': ['b', 'g'],
 'linestyle': '--'}
```

**Notice** that for the last two line segments (those that use datetime.datetime instead of Timestamp (which is fine)), instead of `float` for the price value, you have **strings**.

For example, **`'47.5'`** instead of **`47.5`**

Comment: I was searching yesterday for hours because I thought the mistake is in the difference between "Timestamp" and "datetime". Havent seen the difference in the value part.
Beeing overwhelmed by getting an answer from you again, I deleted by mistake the last 4 hours of my code from yesterday night.. {'me':'jerk'}.
Thank you again, a simple casting float() did the job. It works. Thanks.